# Wireless unavailable in Fedora 17 running on Samsung Series 5

Tags: linux, fedora, wireless-networking

I installed Fedora 17 on my laptop (Samsung Series 5), and everything is OK except the wireless. I've tried to activate it but I couldn't. On the top right corner, "unavailable" is next to the wireless icon.

I can't find `BCM43xx` in the `lspci` report and in forums they suppose that 'BCM43xx' does exist in the report of `lspci`.

Thanks

Comment: `The problem is that in the Internet we don't consider the case when we don't find "BCM43xx" in the "lspci" report.`

I don't quite understand this line, can you make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Me neither, please [edit] your post and fix it if I got that wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Check that you didn't turn off wireless (many laptops have a physical switch, or some magic Fn-cokebottle key to do so).